# How do you restart/force quit the notification center in mavericks

Tags: macos

I am referring to the upper right corner (beside spotlight). Somehow my notification center crashed while I was typing a message and it has been broken for a couple of days now. Is there a way besides restarting my machine? (just curious, i can easily restart it but if there's a way for it to go away without restarting then I'd like that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Activity Monitor, kill `Notification Center` and it'll reload automatically !